# jQuery: how to stop the function that runs periodically

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing systems on Google App Engine and Python. The following jQuery code is used to update the time periodically. The following HTML code is inserted into the `content` div by jQuery Ajax:

HTML:

```
...
{{product.name}}: <br />
Bidding time is approaching: <div id="timeToBid{{product.randomNo}}">{{timeToBid}}</div>
...

$(document).ready(function() {
  function updateTime() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/timeToBid?productId={{product.key.id}}",
      cache: false,
      success: function(returndata){
        $('#timeToBid{{product.randomNo}}').html(returndata);
      }
    });
    setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
  }
  updateTime();
});
```

Sever-side program:

```
class TimetoBid(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        productId = self.request.get('productId')
        product = Product.get_by_id(productId)
        time = str(datetime.datetime.now() - product.bidTime)
        self.response.out.write(message)
```

However, if I click other buttons in the page to update the `content` div, the updateTime() function is still running unless I refresh the whole page. In addition, since the function won't stop, if I enter the page many times, the problem run several times in a second. How to stop the function if the `content` div gets updated with other HTML code?

Comment: Assign the result of `setTimeout` to a variable `timer`. The code that updates the content div can call `clearTimeout(timer)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the result of `setTimeout` to a variable `timer`. The code that updates the content div can call `clearTimeout(timer)`.

UPDATE

Another option would be for the `updateTime()` function to check whether the content div has changed, and stop running.

```
var oldContent;
function removeTimeToBid(str) {
    return str.replace(/<div id="timeToBid.*?<\/div>/, '');
}
function updateTime() {
   var newContent = removeTimeToBid($("#content").html());
   if (newContent != oldContent) { return; }
   $.ajax({
      url: "/timeToBid?productId={{product.key.id}}",
      cache: false,
      success: function(returndata){
        $('#timeToBid{{product.randomNo}}').html(returndata);
      }
   });
   setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
}

function startUpdatingTime() {
    oldContent = removeTimeToBid($("#content").html());
    updateTime();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do that? Could you elaborate more? Furthermore, there are **many** codes that will update the `content` div. I need to implement the mechanism for each of them? Can the function terminate automatically if `content` div gets updated.

Comment: I added a rewrite of `updateTime()` that stops if content gets updated.

Comment: Hi, Barmar. The code suddenly doesn't work, and I don't know why. To test, I just have one line of HTML code: `<div id="timeToBid{{product.randomNo}}"></div>`. And the javascript runs only once and then stops. It finds the `content` different. Would update of the `timeToBid...` div cause the change of `content` div?

Comment: Are you using `startUpdatingTime()` to restart it? You need to use that so that `oldContent` gets initialized correctly.

Comment: Yes, I do use startUpdatingTime(); just add it to the last of your code. As I said, the updateTime() runs only once.

Comment: Is the `timeToBid...` div inside the `content` div? If so, updating the inner div changes the contents of the outer div.

Comment: Yes, you're right. `timeToBid` is inside `content`. How do I fix it then? Just curious, is it possible to test only a portion of `content` (except the `timeToBid` div)?

Comment: See the updated code, which removes that DIV before comparing. I also removed an assignment of `oldContent` -- it was being done in a case where it hadn't changed, so it was redundant.

Comment: Hey, I just found out another solution: I enclosed the whole javascript code with `<div id="testChange"></div>` and then change `content` to `testChange`. And it worked! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You should use setInterval instead setTimeout :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Define variable to enable or disable the refresh function
  window.doRefresh = true;

  function updateTime() {

    //Execute AJAX request only if it is allowed
    if(!window.doRefresh)
        return;

    $.ajax({
      url: "/timeToBid?productId={{product.key.id}}",
      cache: false,
      success: function(returndata){
        $('#timeToBid{{product.randomNo}}').html(returndata);
      }
    });
  }

  //Permits to execute updateTime every seconds until clearInterval is called
  var intervalHandle = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

  $('#myDiv').click(function(){
      //Stop definitely the interval code execution using
      clearInterval(intervalHandle);

      //Or use a variable to disable refreshing
      window.doRefresh = false;

      //Do some stuff...

      //Then enable refreshing like this
      window.doRefresh = true;
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite understand how to do it. Is `myDiv` an id of a button or link?

Comment: `$('#myDiv')` is just a div with a click event for the exemple. The interresting piece of code is how to cancel the interval function or how to disable and enable it defined inside the click event